MAUI Android - System.DllNotFoundException: sqlite3 at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Open
I migrated an MAUI Net 8 project from the Xamarin project.  I used the Mono.Data.SQLite package for the SQLite connection. It's working fine in MAUI iOS. But in Android, it throws an exception as below,
System.DllNotFoundException: sqlite3 at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum flags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool) at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()

Because libsqlite3.so the library is missing in MAUI Android. And I don't want to switch to another SQLite package because it leads to a major code change.
So can you please help us to resolve this issue?

Can you share what sqllite packages your using, as defined in .csproj

I am using this package for SQLite connection,


Mono.Data.Sqlite seems to be a quote old package, with no updates since 2018. I can't comment on it's effectiveness in MAUI apps, but given MAUI is newer than the package, this might be your issue.
If you need Sqllite in your MAUI project, I recommend the following combination of packages which I have working in a couple of projects.
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.8" />

The bundles bring in extra magic to make it work cross platform.
